# ¿Cómo puedo implementar fuerza bruta en un diccionario?

Tags: php

Tengo un algoritmo César para cifrar y descifrar y para puntos extras del trabajo práctico nos piden implementar un ataque de fuerza bruta para encontrar la palabra cifrada. Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo encarar el ejercicio?, No entiendo como implementar el método de fuerza bruta con las palabras que yo ponga para cifrar.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora para leer el diccionario, no tiene nada que ver la búsqueda binaria con lo que pido, pero pensé que iba a servir para orientarme.

```
<?php
$file = "diccionario.txt";
$document = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);


function busqueda_binaria($elemento_a_buscar, $desde, $hasta){
    global $document;
    // Selección de la posición del elemento central.
    $pivot = round(($desde + ($hasta - $desde) / 2), 0);
    echo("Pivot: {$pivot} - Desde: {$desde} - Hasta: {$hasta}\n");
    // Condición de corte.
    if($desde > $hasta) return -1;//si ya no se puede partir la lista es que no lo encontró
    echo("Comparando: ".(strcmp($elemento_a_buscar, $document[$pivot]))."\n");
    
    if(strcmp($elemento_a_buscar, $document[$pivot]) < 0){
        return busqueda_binaria($elemento_a_buscar, $desde, $pivot - 1);
        
    } else if (strcmp($elemento_a_buscar, $document[$pivot]) > 0){
        return busqueda_binaria($elemento_a_buscar, $pivot + 1, $hasta);
        
    } else {
        return $pivot;
    }
}


echo("---------------------\n");

$i = busqueda_binaria(readline(), 0, count($document)-1);
if($i >= 0){
    echo("Encontrado en la posición: {$i}\n");
}else echo("No encontrado\n");`
```

Comment: Es irrelevante el código de búsqueda binaria y no se que tiene que ver con lo que expones, en todo caso deberías haber adjuntado el algoritmo que usas para cifrar. Fuerza bruta significa probar todas las posibles combinaciones en la entrada de tu algoritmo para descifrar una cadena. Por ejemplo, dado tu algoritmo y una cadena cifrada, debes empezar a probar todas las combinaciones posibles o palabras de un diccionario hasta que la salida del algoritmo coincida con la cadena cifrada. Si la salida y la cadena cifrada coinciden, entonces la entrada que originó esa salida es la cadena descifrada.

Comment: Había puesto una respuesta, pero me equivoqué de lenguaje, lo que debes hacer es atacar el cifrador/descifrador con un `for` `$i` de `0` hasta el *numero de símbolos usados* para cifrar, generalmente 27 (`abc...z`). La iteración que muestre texto legible, entonces es la misma que tiene la clave, o sea `$i`.